# Most efficient way for this complicated join/filter?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

So I have a table ENTRIES with this setup:

| ENTRY_ID | SUBCLASS | A_CODE_1 | A_CODE_2 | A_CODE_3 | B_CODE_1 | B_CODE_2 | B_CODE_3 |

I have also have two tables ( REL_A_CODE and REL_B_CODE) listing all relevant A & B codes by subclass:                      | SUBCLASS | REL_A_CODE |         and          | SUBCLASS | REL_B_CODE |

What I am trying to do (in SQL) is efficiently filter this so that I am only left with entries with any of the three A codes being relevant AND any of the three B codes. Note that different subclasses have different relevant A & B codes.

I was able to write a query that does what I want, but it tends to take a long time with a large ENTRIES table:

```
CREATE TABLE RELEVANT_ENTRIES AS SELECT
T1.*
FROM ENTRIES T1
LEFT JOIN REL_A_CODES T2 ON (T1.SUBCLASS = T2.SUBCLASS) AND (T1.A_CODE_1 = T2.REL_A_CODE)
LEFT JOIN REL_A_CODES T3 ON (T1.SUBCLASS = T3.SUBCLASS) AND (T1.A_CODE_2 = T3.REL_A_CODE)
LEFT JOIN REL_A_CODES T4 ON (T1.SUBCLASS = T4.SUBCLASS) AND (T1.A_CODE_3 = T4.REL_A_CODE)
LEFT JOIN REL_B_CODES T5 ON (T1.SUBCLASS = T5.SUBCLASS) AND (T1.B_CODE_1 = T5.REL_B_CODE)
LEFT JOIN REL_B_CODES T6 ON (T1.SUBCLASS = T6.SUBCLASS) AND (T1.B_CODE_2 = T6.REL_B_CODE)
LEFT JOIN REL_B_CODES T7 ON (T1.SUBCLASS = T7.SUBCLASS) AND (T1.B_CODE_3 = T7.REL_B_CODE)
WHERE (T2.REL_A_CODE IS NOT NULL OR T3.REL_A_CODE IS NOT NULL OR T4.REL_A_CODE IS NOT NULL) AND
      (T5.REL_B_CODE IS NOT NULL OR T6.REL_B_CODE IS NOT NULL OR T7.REL_B_CODE IS NOT NULL)
```

This does output exactly what I want, but I was wondering if there was cleaner/more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I can't think of an optimization knowing so little about those tables in terms of structure and volumes. Please first make sure you have fresh statistics on those tables. If some statistics are stale, the run dbms_stats.gather_table_stats for those tables. Then see the explain plan. Some indexes might help, but that depends also on what columns you need to fetch from what table. Does every join have to be left join? Why not inner join, considering that where is not null conditions?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell about performance without insight but your SQL most
likely could be done without so many joins. Try it like below and compare the results:

```sql
-- option 1 
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
FROM ENTRIES T1
LEFT JOIN CODES T2 ON ( (T1.SUBCLASS = T2.SUBCLASS) AND 
                        (T2.REL_A_CODE IN(T1.A_CODE_1, T1.A_CODE_2, T1.A_CODE_3) OR T2.REL_B_CODE IN(T1.B_CODE_1, T1.B_CODE_2, T1.B_CODE_3) )
                      )
WHERE (T2.REL_A_CODE IS NOT NULL OR T2.REL_B_CODE IS NOT NULL)

--  Option 2
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
FROM ENTRIES T1
LEFT JOIN CODES T2 ON (T1.SUBCLASS = T2.SUBCLASS) AND 
    ( 
      (T1.A_CODE_1 = T2.REL_A_CODE) OR 
      (T1.A_CODE_2 = T2.REL_A_CODE) OR 
      (T1.A_CODE_3 = T2.REL_A_CODE) OR
      --
      (T1.B_CODE_1 = T2.REL_B_CODE) OR 
      (T1.B_CODE_2 = T2.REL_B_CODE) OR 
      (T1.B_CODE_3 = T2.REL_B_CODE)
   )
WHERE (T2.REL_A_CODE IS NOT NULL OR T2.REL_B_CODE IS NOT NULL)

--  Option 3
SELECT T1.*
FROM ENTRIES T1
WHERE EXISTS( Select 1 
              From CODES 
              Where   SUBCLASS = T1.SUBCLASS And
                      (
                          (InStr('/' || T1.A_CODE_1 || '/' || T1.A_CODE_2 || '/' || T1.A_CODE_3 || '/', '/' || REL_A_CODE || '/') > 0) 
                        OR
                          (InStr('/' || T1.B_CODE_1 || '/' || T1.B_CODE_2 || '/' || T1.B_CODE_3 || '/', '/' || REL_B_CODE || '/') > 0) 
                      )  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried both of your options, they did take a good amount longer to run than what I originally had. I’ve tried similar methods to yours in the past, and from what I’ve seen for this query having an OR or IN in the join condition causes significant a slowdown. For reference, the ENTRIES table has about 90,000,000 rows, REL_CODE_A has about 100,000, and REL_CODE_B has about 300,000.

Comment: @Jsf4332 Maybe you could try option 3 - no joins - just where exists.... there is an OR, though, but the check fetches just 1 row...